# Change button text after click, then change it back after clicking again

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am trying to change the text of a Button every time its  clicked.

Button Starts as "ON". When I click it the first time it should change to "OFF", and when I click it again, it should change back to On.

I understand how to change it to "OFF" when clicked, but I am unsure as to how to check for a secondary click so I can change the text back to "ON".

Here is my code so far:

```
private void OrdersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       OrdersButton.Text = " Turn Orders Off";
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
    private void OrdersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OrdersButton.Text == "Turn Orders On")
        {
            OrdersButton.Text = "Turn Orders Off";
        }
        else if (OrdersButton.Text == "Turn Orders Off")
        {
            OrdersButton.Text = "Turn Orders On";
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

I can see several possible problems with that and can offer a more object oriented solution:
Adding a property that keeps track of the current "state":

```
    private bool _IsOn;

    public bool IsOn
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsOn;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsOn = value;
            OrdersButton.Text = _IsOn ? "On" : "Off";
        }
    }
```

and using the event handler to simply toggle the property:

```
private void OrdersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     IsOn = !IsOn;
}
```

That way it's easier to access the information later on and you can easily replace on/off with whatever you like - even globalize/localize it if required. I think it's a very bad programming practice to have code depend on the text that is on the display...

EDIT: Also, wouldn't using a checkbox or a togglebutton make more sense? Other than the visual representation being different, it does what you want out of the box...

Comment: +1, and strongly agreed with your edit. Toggle buttons that change their caption are notorious examples of *bad* design because they confuse the user. It's very difficult to know which state is current and which one you're toggling to—the thing the button says or the thing it *doesn't* say. A checkbox is by far the better alternative. And remember that checkbox captions should almost always be phrased positively to avoid creating a double-negative. More on this issue can be found over on our UX Q&A site. Specifically this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/

Answer (score 3):

Just test the current text:

```
OrdersButton.Text = OrdersButton.Text.EndsWith("Off") ? "Turn Orders On" : "Turn Orders Off";
```

Edit: As Cody points out in comments below, that doesn't work well with localization. For something that can more easily be localized use ViewState (assuming the initial text is to turn orders on):

```
bool ordersWereOn = (ViewState["OrdersAreOn"] as bool?) ?? false;
ViewState["OrdersAreOn"] = !ordersWereOn;
OrdersButton.Text = ordersWereOn ? "Turn Orders On" : "Turn Orders Off";
```

Comment: Note that this is using the [inline-if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) operator. Just FYI. +1 for neat one-liner.

Comment: It might be a neat one-liner, but this approach falls flat on its face as soon as you localize the UI.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this.
As for me, I would probably use `Tag` attribute of `Control` because:

1. It is being stored into a button's variable. You don't need any external variables
2. All code can be written in a single method
3. You can always access it from other methods \ controls

Here is the example code:

```
private void OrdersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool value = (OrdersButton.Tag as bool?) ?? true;
    OrdersButton.Tag = !value;

    OrdersButton.Text = "Turn Orders " + (value ? "On" : "Off");
}
```

You might also set default `Tag` value (true or false) and remove checking for null value.
You will also be always able to do access it this way:

```
public void DoSomeImportantThings()
{
    var areOrdersTurnedOn = (bool)OrdersButton.Tag;
}
```

It is not the best approach - it is just another one.
For example, *Roman Gruber* has shown, probably, the best answer using properties with text changing logic encapsulated into a setter.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button4.Text == "Show Password")
    {
        textBox2.PasswordChar = '\0';
        button4.Text = "Hide Password";
    }
    else
    {
        textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
        button4.Text = "Show Password";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be your Button als XML in Avalonia :

```
<Button Width="..." Grid.Row="..." Grid.Column="..." HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsVisible="true" Click="OnClickStart" Content="Start"/>
```

Then you can code in View that method : OnClickStart :

```
private void OnClickStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button startBtn = (Button) sender ;

        if (startBtn.Content is "Start")
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("the start btn is pressed");
            startBtn.Content = "Stop";
        }else if (startBtn.Content is "Stop")
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("the stop btn is pressed!");
            startBtn.Content = "Start";
        }
}
```