# How do I set the Text of a WPF Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I do not know how to display text on a button.

Now here is the source of my problem. I have those three buttons I want to display a small text: 'Start', 'Stop' and 'Reset'.

```
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace Program.src.View.Main
{
    public class LowerActionPanel : StackPanel
    {
        public LowerActionPanel()
        {
            this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            this.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            Button startButton = new Button();
            startButton.Width = 90;
            startButton.Height = 25;
            startButton.Text = "Text"; //(here the problem lies)
            this.Children.Add(startButton);

            Button stopButton = new Button();
            stopButton.Width = 90;
            stopButton.Height = 25;
            this.Children.Add(stopButton);

            Button resetButton = new Button();
            resetButton.Width = 90;
            resetButton.Height = 25;
            this.Children.Add(resetButton);
        }
    }
}
```

In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400421/change-button-text-after-click-then-change-it-back-after-clicking-again) they use the .Text without any problem whatsoever which makes me think it is possible to just use this, or am I just mistaken?

Comment: I guess you are looking for the wrong `Property`, have you tried to use `Button.Content`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content

Comment: In your question you posted a link to the button documentation. You should re read the line where it says "Button is a ContentControl. Its content property is Content. "  It has no Text property. Which is why you can't set it's Text property. Stack Overflow is not a 100% reliable source of wisdom. When you put some text between the tags of a button in XAML what happens is a textblock is set to content and the text of that textblock is set to the string. I also strongly recommend using xaml rather than code for your ui wherever possible.

Comment: @Andy XAML was honestly too much for me and from using tkInter I was used to just hard coding everything

Comment: If you are struggling with xaml then come on in and join the chat room, we can help you in understanding and terminilogy used in wpf [SO WPF chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf).

Comment: thanks @XAMlMAX, yet the karma threshhold of 20 is keeping me out of there.

Comment: Ah sorry dude, didn't know there was a limit!

Comment: Show how you're adding an instance of `LowerActionPanel` to the `Window`.

Comment: Also, if you're just beginning, inhering from `StackPanel` isn't going to make your life easier. Just add the controls (buttons) directly to a top-level element of the WIndow, like a `Grid`

Comment: @ardila Well my GUI needs the same building blocks multiple times so i might jsut make my life easier with that. got it to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using WPF. The last example link you provide uses WinForms. WinForms offers the property Text on a button while the WPF button does not. If you want to set the content of a WPF button, you should use the Content property.

Like so:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "Click here";
```

Or using an object initializer:

```
var button = new Button {Content = "Click here"};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing should probably be a usercontrol rather than a custom control.

Maybe something like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpf_99.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_99"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="25"
         >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="92"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Name="StartButton" Content="Start"/>
    <Button Name="StopButton" Content="Stop"/>
    <Button Name="ResetButton" Content="Reset"/>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Usage:

```
 <Window
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_99"
    >

<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

You might find this useful:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32610.wpf-layout-lab.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I will avoid XAML for now until I can properly code C#, for now i will stick with hardcoding the gui