# How to change lable of button on Ribbon (Word Add In VSTO) when click button at CustomTaskPane

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon, word-addins, customtaskpane

I've create two buttons, **Status** button with default "Open" in my **Word add-in Ribbon** and **ChangeStatus** button at my CustomTaskPane.

How to change lable of Status button from "Open" to "Close" (on **Word add-in Ribbon**) when click **ChangeStatus** button at **CustomTaskPane**.

[image]

This code Ribbon:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
namespace TestWordAddIn
{
    public partial class Demo
    {
        private Detail myDetail;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;
        private void Demo_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnStatus_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            // create new customtaskpane
            myDetail = new Detail();
            myCustomTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myDetail, "Error List");
            myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
            myCustomTaskPane.Width = 380;
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This code UserControl in CustomTaskPane:

```
namespace TestWordAddIn
{
    public partial class Detail : UserControl
    {
        private Word.Application wApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        public Detail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Detail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnChangeStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change status "Open" button to "Close" button in Ribbon when click ChangeStatus button at CustomTaskPane  
        }
    }
}
```

This code ThisAddIn.css:

```
namespace TestWordAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
    
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change button text after click, then change it back after clicking again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400421/change-button-text-after-click-then-change-it-back-after-clicking-again)

Comment: No, my requirement is to apply for word add in vsto. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.btn.label = ...